# How to pivot/merge rows based on condition in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

| record | name1 | name2 | to_merge | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STEVE | null | false | 30 | null |
| 2 | JOHN | null | true | 43 | null |
| 3 | null | LAURA | true | null | 66 |
| 4 | JEN | null | false | 18 | null |

I want this to be the output:

| record | name1 | name2 | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STEVE | null | 30 | null |
| 2 | JOHN | LAURA | 43 | 66 |
| 3 | JEN | null | 18 | null |

This means I want to merge the rows with a TRUE value in the to_merge field. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select * except(to_merge)
from your_table
where not to_merge
union all
select max(name1), max(name2),
  max(value1), max(value2)
from your_table
where to_merge
```

if applied to data in your question - output is

[image]